# how to get stats of a specific date via antonioribeiro/tracker laravel package

Tags: php, laravel

For Storing user tracking information, I used [antonioribeiro/tracker](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) laravel package.

In this package to get sessions (visits) from the past day , should use like this:

```
$sessions = Tracker::sessions(60 * 24);
```

But I am trying to get visits of a specific day (for Example **yesterday** or the day before yesterday) or a specific date range like form `01/22/2016` to `01/25/2016`.

For yesterday page views I try this:

```
$yesterday = Carbon::yesterday();
$today     = Carbon::today();

$yesVisits = Tracker::sessions($yesterday->diffInMinutes($today))->count();
```

But it returns all page views from `00:00:00` of `yesterday` to `00:00:00` of `today`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Just set the date interval to be between the day you want and the day + 1? Here is the full carbon doc to help you do that: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/